# Convert .html file to .txt using cp | error: cp: cannot stat '/*.html': No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash

```
#!/bin/bash
# Make a txt copy of any html files

for value in $1/*.html
do
        if [[ $value == *.html ]]; then
            cp $value $1/$( basename -s .html $value ).txt
        fi
done
```

ERROR:
cp: cannot stat '/*.html': No such file or directory
cp: failed to access 'index.html/*.txt': Not a directory

Comment: pass part of the filename as command line parameter

Comment: I did, I am passing the whole file name as ./convert_html_to_txt.sh index.html for example and throws the error

Comment: @ClaudioLopez, it is obvious error why you are giving a file name where you should give a directory name so lets take example `/index.html/a.html` will not be there so system is complaining it is not there. what I believe yo want to copy 1 sort of html files to another directory if yes then confirm once.

Comment: @ClaudioLopez, could you please check my solution once and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: `Convert .html file to .txt using cp` Huh? `cp` doesn't convert anything. Are you simply talking about copying to another file with a different *extension*? If you want to strip the html tags, then there is a utility `html2txt` that does a good job (make sure you look at the options, e.g. `-utf8`, etc.., if you use it)

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `$1` in the below statement is the first command line parameter.

```
$1/*.html
```

In your code, it is expecting the parent **directory name** containing the HTML files. Suppose, you parent directory is `/home/user/my_html_files`, then if you pass this as the command line parameter, then all the HTML files inside this directory will be considered.

```
# ./convert_html_to_txt.sh /home/user/my_html_files
```

The above will result into `/home/user/my_html_files/*.html` in your code. If your HTML file is in current directory, just pass `.` as the command line parameter (`.` denotes current directory)

Comment: I believe problem is not only that, user is giving a file in arguments, and doing wrong check on file existing or not(since for loop only going through html files so I believe this check could be skipped here).

Comment: may be. only OP can clarify :=)

Comment: @hashbrown you were right. I just copied this the for loop somewhere else and did not realize $1 was called before any file is checked against the if statement insede the code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to pass a directory name(with complete path) to script and second since you are looping through only HTML files in directory so you need not to do check for it again rather you could put check condition on its copy either it copied as `.txt` successfully or not. I believe most probably you are looking for this kind of solution.

```
cat script.ksh
for value in $1/*.html
do
   temp=${value%.*}
   echo cp "$value" "$1/$temp.txt"
   if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
   then
       echo "File named $value copied successfully to "$value" "$1/$temp.txt"
   else
       echo "Please check file named $value NOT copied to "$value" "$1/$temp.txt"
   fi
done
```

Then run the `script.ksh` as `script.ksh "/directory_name/with_full_path"`. Also I have put `echo` before `cp` command so once you see command is printing correct by above script you could remove it then.